# Golangci-lint. Ошибка после установки

Tags: golang, linter

После успешной установки с официального [сайта](https://golangci-lint.run/usage/install/):
Для Manjaro Linux командой:

```
curl -sSfL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golangci/golangci-lint/master/install.sh | sh -s -- -b $(go env GOPATH)/bin v1.32.2
```

при попытке проверки версии

```
golangci-lint --version
```

терминал выводит ошибку:

```
command not found: golangci-lint
```

Ничего внятного нагуглить не удалось.
С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Поищите бинарник в папке `$GOPATH/bin`

Comment: расскажите как вы установили

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, обновил описание вопроса, указал по-человечески источник, систему и команду установки. Посмотрите, пожалуйста)

Comment: Был ли какой-то вывод от команды установки? На мой взгляд v1.32.2 в конце команды лишние

Comment: @УстьянцевБорис, вывод команды следующий:
`golangci/golangci-lint info checking GitHub for tag 'v1.32.2'`

`golangci/golangci-lint info found version: 1.32.2 for v1.32.2/linux/amd64`
`golangci/golangci-lint info installed /home/madpotato/go/bin/golangci-lint`

Comment: Ну тут ясно написано что установилось в /home/madpotato/go/bin/golangci-lint. А не запускается глобально из-за того что этот каталог у вас не в PATH скорее всего

Comment: @Stanlyzoolo покажите что у вас лежит в переменной PATH.

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, вот содержимое)
 `/home/madpotato/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вам нужно добавить BIN_DIR в перемунную PATH. так как оттуда ОС понимает, где искать бинари.

Для этого открываем `~/.bashrc`, если нету, то создаем.
добавляем конфигурирование PATH в вашу консоль.

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
```

Первая команда настроит вам GOPATH. Вам нужно указать путь относительно вашей системы. 
Вторая добавит bin директории к PATH. Перезагружаем консоль, чтобы подтянулись настройки. Теперь вы можете исполнять ваши команыды.

Comment: я добавил в файл bashrc (в самый конец) код выше. Закрыл/открыл консоль и все равно не видит.

прописываю эти команды в терминале, они работают до следующей перезагрузки терминала. Я что то не понял(

Comment: вы отметили вопрос как верный. в данный момент у вас получилось решить проблему или все еще не работает?

Comment: да я отметил проблему как решенную. Ведь вначале вопрос решился. 
Осталось только закрепить результат, чтобы не требовалось прописывать Ваши команды при каждом открытии терминала. Помогите, пожалуйста, еще с этим

Comment: если вы добавли это в ~/.bashrc, то они уже должны быть видны вам каждый раз. когда открываете консоль. вы точно добавили? если да. то покажите значение ~/.bashrc. какая операционная система у вас установлена?

Comment: система установлена Manjaro Linux.
Код, который расположен в файле .bashrc, здесь: https://pastebin.com/nt5j6ahb

Comment: я могу предположить, что из-за return или где-то еще происходит ошибка и не доходит исполнения до конца.  мы можете последние три строчки перенести в самое начало испронения(строка 4),  либо проверить наличие переменных после открытия терминала (запустите printenv ), либо дебажить и понять что успевает исполнять ваша консоль.